# Multi threaded application on server slower than single threaded (unlike in JUnit tests)

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, debugging

I've switched in my application from a single to a multi threaded routine.

This works pretty fine in the JUnit tests. When running it with `10` threads, the test needs `195` ms to complete and when running it with only one thread the application takes `406` ms to finish. So there clearly is a performance advantage.

But when running it on the server, the application now needs much longer than when it was only single threaded.

Basically, my application reads a line in a csv file, puts one of its value in a set and prints the line to another file.
The size of the input file in the JUnit tests is about `35` lines long, the one on the server about `6 000 000` lines long.

The set in which those values are put is a synchronized `HashSet` which can contain `Long` objects.

I'm monitoring my application with the Java VisualVM but unfortunately I don't know what to look for.

Do you have any hints for me on how to solve this performance crisis?

---

P. S.: Most of the time my threads are marked as waiting, but I don't know if they are really waiting or if they are just too fast for the Java VisualVM to display it.

---

To further clarify my routine: I read the file single threaded, but as soon as the line is read I pass the resulting object to a `Runnable` that puts it into a set and prints it into another file. Meanwhile the next lines are read and passed to other threads.

---

As I can see it in my log file, the threads are doing something and aren't just waiting. But there are certain *jumps*, periods longer than `100` ms where nothing is happening.

---

One of those *jumps:*

```
2011-04-08 12:27:16,580 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 7070927
2011-04-08 12:27:16,580 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 9058759
2011-04-08 12:27:16,580 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 7030928
2011-04-08 12:27:16,580 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 15301035
2011-04-08 12:27:16,684 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 7700929
2011-04-08 12:27:16,684 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 17116545
2011-04-08 12:27:16,685 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 4933581
2011-04-08 12:27:16,685 DEBUG [Thread-10]  runnables.Runner - 2861116
```

Note: No GC happened at that time.

---

As written in a comment below: I am using a threadpool. My threads are fighting* over the same output file. They all write to a `synchronized` method.

---

Even if I reduce the size of my tread pool to one, the performance is still horrible. Nothing compared to the previous implementation. Wouldn't that rule out things like IO dependency or thread switching?

---

I've modified my code now so that inside the `Runnable` nearly nothing is done. No `Set`, no writing. Just one log statement. And still I get those `jumps`.
 So I rule out the writing or `Set` problem proposed by some. And when running only one thread, I also got these idle times. So thread switiching also doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: Have you tried to run a unit test with a long file? Also, it's not clear how do you read the file by multiple threads.

Comment: Thank you for your hint. See my update at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Probably need to see some code to help diagnose this one.

Comment: Probably synchronization of read from/write to file and setting hash set takes longer than the same work done by one thread without it. Your unit test probably works better, because input/output files are small and are cached by OS.

Comment: do your threads use the multiple cores on your server?

Comment: Are you using a form of thread pooling or do you wind up with 6 million threads? Also do thr threads attempt to write content to the same output file or different output files (i.e. Are they fighting over that resource?)

Comment: I am using a threadpool. Yes, they are *fighting* over the same file. They all write to a `synchronized` method.

Comment: So if they are fighting for a resources then I think you should increase the around of data that is read by one thread - for example to 10000 csv lines and release file for other thread. Then you need to do some processing and when your data is ready to insert to hash set do this as fast as possible without locking set to long. Using larger chunk of data will greatly reduce synchronization overhead, because thread will need to access to resource only once instead of 10000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what the problem was, but it seems that it was caused by a bad implementation of the [`Executor`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) interface.

I'm now using

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(nThreads);
```

and everything is working fine.

- Duration of single threaded routine:
  `17.12` min
- Duration of `10` threaded    routine:
  `13.45` min

---

I found the bad piece of code:

```
Thread.sleep(100);
```

was invoked when the thread queue was full.

Answer (score 7):

Your test file is very small, so it's likely read completely by any read-ahead layer in the whole I/O stack.  That makes the whole execution CPU bound.  With more threads, you use more CPUs and get it done faster.

The real file, OTOH, is much longer, so the problem becomes IO-bound.  The CPUs spend most of the time waiting for the read data.  On a single thread, there's no contention and probably the IO is more linear; while the multithreaded version is more likely to generate lots of disc seeks (by far the slowest operation you can do on today's hardware)

As a rule of thumb, if you read data from disc or network and don't do heavy processing on it, it's better to go single threaded.

Comment: I'm reading the file single threaded and create an object of every csv line. This object is passed to the `Runnable`. Then the multi threaded part starts. So I never access the input file with more than one thread.

Answer (score 1):

The "jumps" you are reffering to are the switching times between the threads. Because overall execution time is limited the execution time for one thread becomes smaller the more threads you have. If you have to many threads your scheduler ends up in switching the threads and no thread does any work. Switching from one thread to another costs a certain fixed amount of time. if your threads don't use more than one core and do the exact same thing then you end up in a worse speed when comparing multithreaded with singlethreaded.